# Prove that a recursively given sequence converges from any starting number from interval $(2,\infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

First of all, there are many problems of the same nature here but they are all given the first point $a_1$. Here however, the $a_n$ sequence must be convergent for EVERY $a_1$ from $(2,\infty)$. I literally have no idea how to tackle this and I am actually ashamed of myself because I cannot solve this.

$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{3}{2+a_n} $$

The sequence is of real numbers. $a_1$ is any number from $(2,\infty)$.

WolframAlpha gives me [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_%28n%2B1%29%3D3%2F%282%2Ba_n%29) but again no idea how it came to those $c_1$ and $c_2$ and the whole explicit formula. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the recursion in question is $$a_{n+1}=\frac 3{2+a_n}$$

We are given that $a_0≥2$.

Note:  it is clear that if the limit exists it is $1$.  (the equation $L=\frac 3{2+L}$ has solutions $\{1,-3\}$.  It is not obvious that a limit exists, however.

One idea is to split the sequence in two, even and odd terms.  If you try some examples you'll see that the terms alternate, greater than and less than $1$.  But those less than $1$ are strictly increasing and those greater than $1$ are strictly decreasing. Note that we have the recursion $$a_{n+2}=\frac 3{2+a_{n+1}}=\frac {6+3a_n}{7+2a_n}$$
Again it is easy to see that, if this has a limit, the limit is $1$.

To show that this has a limit, we suppose that $a_n<1$ and seek to show that this implies $$a_n<a_{n+2}<1$$

(this will suffice, because an increasing bounded sequence must approach a limit and in this case that limit must be $1$).

Pf:

1) $\frac {6+3a_n}{7+2a_n}<1$ as that inequality is equivalent to $6+3a_n<7+2a_n$ which in turn is equivalent to $a_n<1$.

2) $\frac {6+3a_n}{7+2a_n}>a_n$ as that inequality is equivalent to $6+3a_n>7a_n+2a_n^2$ which in turn is equivalent to $3 > 2a_n+a_n^2$ which follows from the fact that both $a_n$ and $a_n^2$ are $<1$.

Proving the analog assuming that $a_n>1$ is similar.

Comment: From where does the 6+3*a_n and 7+2*a_n come from though? Aren't even ones 2*a_n and odd 2*a_n+1? I do not understand this part. Ps: its a_0>2 (strictly) but it does not matter that much anyways I suppose.

Comment: There was a typo in what I wrote.  I meant:  $a_{n+2}=\frac 3{2+a_{n+1}}=\frac 3{2+\frac 3{2+a_n}}$ Then multiply numerator and denominator by $2+a_n$ to get $a_{n+2}=\frac {3(2+a_n)}{2(2+a_n)+3}$. Then simplify.

Comment: By "even" and "odd" I was referring to the indices.  Thus $\{a_0,a_2, a_4...\}$ are the "even" terms and $\{a_1,a_3,a_5,...\}$ are the "odd" terms.

Comment: Alright, alright yes of course -.- I'm too tired I suppose, thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_0>-2 .$ Then $a_1>0$, and by induction, $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Let $D_n=1-a_n$. We have $$n\geq 1\implies |D_{n+1}|=|a_{n+1}-1|=|\frac {3}{2+a_n}-1|=|\frac {1-a_n}{2+a_n}|=|\frac {D_n}{2+a_n}|\leq|D_n/2|.$$ By induction we have $n\geq 1\implies |D_n|\leq 2^{1-n}|D_1|. $ Therefore $$0=\lim_{n\to \infty}D_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-a_n).$$